# Mini mac server returning:- attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, opendirectory

I have an Open Directory(OD) server running on OSX 10.8.5.  I have software connecting to it (a web interface) which is searching the LDAP for users.  So I run the query on the web app, and look in "Server" on the server to check out the Open Directory/LDAP logs.  I see no data appearing, but I do see a slightly older message reading...

```
<date> <time> <domain> slapd[162]" conn=-1 op=0: attribute "entryCSN" index delete failure
```

Is this something of concern?  Might this explain why a wildcard search via the web app returns the same single user (used to be 4 users, now it's just 1).